# Change only file permissions in a folder NOT RECURSIVELLY

Tags: chmod

I have a lot of files in one specific folder, and I want to change the permissions only for files and only in this folder (not subfolders), how can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
find your_folder -type f -exec chmod your_permissions {} \;
```

This command changes the permissions only for regular files in the selected folder (replace "your_folder" and "your_permissions" with the appropriate values).

If you only want to change the permissions for files in your_folder itself and not in its subfolders you can add -maxdepth:

```
find your_folder -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec chmod your_permissions {} \;
```

Comment: what means "{} \" at the end?

Comment: Ok you beat me to it :) have an upvote.

Comment: @lpFranz `{}` stands for what `find` has found.

Comment: @lpFranz `{}` tells find to insert the find results into the formula, the `\` in front of the semicolon is just an escape character.

Comment: chmod g+r \*.\* -> The "\*.\*" do the same thing? I've received this tip.

Comment: `. ` designates the current directory, not the files in it.

Comment: Please please please! `*.*` is just calling for trouble this matches all and everything even the parent directory in some cases.

Comment: This command is setting permissions for all files recursivelly, this is not what I need, I need to set permissions only for files nested in root folder.

Comment: I just edited my answer.